# Filter by a column value in a 3D matrix in R

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

Edit: I've included a reproducible example.

I am trying to do some simple operation in one of my matrices. My matrices are 3D arrays which contain capture-recapture data.

**Rows** are individuals
**Columns from 1 to 7** are sampling occasions (years)
**Column 8** sex of the individual: 1 males 2 females

```
libray(abind)
CH <- array(c(1,0,1,1,1,1,0), dim = c(5,7,10))
sex <- c(1,1,2,2,1)
CH_with_sex <- abind(CH, array(sex, replace(dim(CH), 2, 1)), along = 2)

CH_with_sex

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    1
[2,]    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    2
[4,]    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    2
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    1
[2,]    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    2
[4,]    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    2
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    1
```

```
dim(CH_with_sex)
[1]  5  8 10
```

My aim is to separate males and females from this 3D array and have 2 different arrays: one for the males and another one for females. I thought of making it by filtering for the column 8  but I can't find the way to do it. I end up breaking or losing the matrix structure. Any advice?

My desired output would be this for males:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    1
[2,]    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    1    1    1
[2,]    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    1
```

And this for females:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    2
[2,]    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    2


, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    2
[2,]    1    0    0    1    1    1    1    2
```

Comment: Hi! Could you provide a minimal and reproducible data set using `dput`?

Comment: And please include the desired output.  "Filtering" is ambiguous here:  what if rep 1 has more males than rep 2?  What shape would you want to get?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I did both things. Hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `x` is your three-dimensional array `CH_with_sex`, and `l` is a list of two three-dimensional arrays splitting `x` by sex.

```r
d <- dim(x)
f <- function(i) x[i, , , drop = FALSE]
l <- c(tapply(seq_len(d[1L]), x[, d[2L], 1L], f, simplify = FALSE))

dim(l[[1]])
## [1]  3  8 10
dim(l[[2]])
## [1]  2  8 10
```

Comment: No problem. You are [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to accept helpful answers by clicking the check mark at the top left.